# added navigation property on existing entity is not saved

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

Looking at the following code:

```
var existingBlog = ... // get existing blog somehow
List<Post> newPosts = ... // get new posts somehow
existingBlog.Posts.Add(newPosts);
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    context.Entry(existingBlog).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

why are the newPosts not added to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Why you use like that? Maybe try to another way

```
var existingBlog = ... // get existing blog somehow
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var newPost = new Post { Title = "some title", BlogId = existingBlog.Id };
    context.Add(newPost);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I know that I can do that, but in fact I have many posts to add (see my update), so I should loop over them and add them to the context... I thought there would be a cleaner way...

Answer (score 0):

What if you add the Posts after you start tracking?

```
var existingBlog = ... // get existing blog somehow
List<Post> newPosts = ... // get new posts somehow
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    context.Entry(existingBlog).State = EntityState.Modified;
    existingBlog.Posts.AddRange(newPosts);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```